# Java Mail with Attachment-Attachment file location not found

Tags: java, email

My code for sending email without attachment works fine. But when I try to send an email wth attachment, I am getting an error message

'C:\Temp\test.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)'
The code is below:
'

```
  package com.abe.test;
    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.activation.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;


public class TestJavaMail {

    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "from@gmail.com";
        final String password = "xxxx";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse("to@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject 1");
            message.setText("PFA");
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            String file = "C:\\Temp";
            String fileName = "test.txt";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);

            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            message.setContent(multipart);

            System.out.println("Sending");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    }
```

Do I need to set any ClassPATH or anything else to get the file attachment working?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt it relates to CLASSPATH. Is the file there? You might also try changing all forward slashes in the path to double backward slashes.

Comment: What's the actual exception being thrown? Are you sure the file you're specifying exists? And you've changed at least one thing in your code since you ran it to get that error, because it wouldn't compile with `fileName` undeclared - is there anything other than that commented-out line?

Comment: I have upated the code to:String file = "C://";
         String fileName = "test.txt";
         DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
         
         messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
         messageBodyPart.setFileName(fileName);                                                                                                                 Still getting the error message: C:\ (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: Do you want to update the code in the question, where it can be formatted properly?

Comment: Some reson formatting is not working. Do you know whether this is a problem on classpath, do I need to set any class path to access the file?

Comment: Code is update now. Any idea why it can't find the file

Comment: `file` should be `"c:\\temp\\test.txt"`; the `FileDataSource` constructor requires a full path.